# Complex numbers in programming

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand complex numbers and I thought that if I could get a source code, it would help me. Like many people, I don't get what $i$ does (Square root of $-1$). I got some code on the net which I posted below. As you can see, there is no $i$. Does that mean that we can ignore it?

I am also trying to understand the Discrete Fourier Transform and I don't get this expression:

```
e^(ix) = cos(x) + i sin(x)
```

Since $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and it's impossible, I tried to replace it by $1$ and it doesn't work. I did this since the source code below doesn't include $i$ anywhere so I though that maybe I could just replace it by $1$.

```
struct complex
{
    float real;
    float imag;
};

struct complex sum(struct complex t1, struct complex t2)
{
    struct complex t;
    t.real = t1.real + t2.real;
    t.imag = t1.imag + t2.imag;
    return t;
} 

struct complex product(struct complex t1, struct complex t2)
{
    struct complex t;
    t.real = t1.real * t2.real - t1.imag * t2.imag;
    t.imag = t1.real * t2.imag + t1.imag * t2.real;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: "I got some code on the net which I posted below. As you can see, there is no i. Does that mean that we can ignore it?" Ignore what? What is this code trying to do?

Comment: Also, if you aren't familiar with complex numbers, then you'll struggle to understand what the equation $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$ actually means - it is to do with writing complex numbers in [_polar form_](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/polar-form-of-a-complex-number)

Comment: @JohnDoe I think what he is trying to say is that there is no "i" in the code above.

Comment: There is no explicit "i" constant in the code because the code simulates the operations (sum or multiplication). There is always an "i" but only conceptually.

Comment: You don't have to understand complex numbers. But they won't go away if you don't, sorry!

Comment: In your source code, complex number t = t.real + t.imag;  In t.imag the imag suffix is the equivalent of multiplying that component by $i$ in more standard mathematical notation.  Or, going the other way if $z = a+ bi$ then z.real = a and z.imag = b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an abstract algebra point of view, a complex number can be defined as a cartesian product of two real numbers.

$$
\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} =  ((a,b) | a \in \mathbb{R},b \in \mathbb{R})
$$

In yours struct, which represents a general complex number, a is 'real' and b is 'imag', referring to the real and imaginary part of a complex number. 
Addition and multiplication in the field $\mathbb{C}$:

$$
(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c,b+d) \\
(a,b) * (c,d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc)
$$

So basically, a complex number can be considered a combination of two real numbers. This i is just a notation to discern between the real and imaginary part.

Comment: Ok so there is a way to use complex number in programming. So if I wanted to program the formula: e^(ix), there is a way?

Comment: sure, the complex exponential $e^{a+ib}= e^{a}\cos(b) +j \ e^{a}\sin(b)$, so in our set form this would be $ exp(\{a,b\}) = \{e^{a}\cos(b),e^{a}\sin(b)\}$ (curly brackets denote set). Note that in your example $a$ equals zero. 
Again you can see there is no explicit $i$. The $i$ can be implicitly thought before the second set element.  

If you do not understand the fomulas itself, I suggest you take a look into complex function analysis.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. Still, I will look at complex function analysis as you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code above does not contain the definition of $i = \sqrt{-1}$ as a separate entity. What is does is storing a complex number in the structure `complex` as two floating numbers. For example, the number $z = 1 + 2i$ is going to be stored as

```
 struct complex z;
 z.real = 1;
 z.imag = 2;
```

In this sense, you can define $i$ as

```
struct complex i;
i.real = 0;
i.imag = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit "i" constant in the code above because it's purpose is to only simulate operations on complex numbers. You should always think that a `struct complex` has an "i" but is not placed explicitly. You can think about a program that does operations using fractions:

```
struct Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};
```

And you can do this:

```
struct Fraction x;
x.numerator = 10;
x.denominator = 20;
```

This is conceptually equivalent to: $\frac{10}{20}$ but there is no fraction sign in the code (the little bar between the numerator and the denominator).

Comment: So it means that usually, you don't need to use i ? Especially in e^(ix) = cos(x) + i sin(x), removing i, I can program it, but if I want to keep it, I have now way to turn that into code.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, the code gives an implementation of a structure that stores a complex number, and defines the addition and multiplication operators on two complex numbers.

In symbols,

$$C_1 + C_2 = (a_1+b_1i) + (a_2 + b_2i) = (a_1 + a_2) + (b_1 + b_2)i$$

$$C_1 \cdot C_2 = (a_1+b_1i) \cdot (a_2 + b_2i) = (a_1a_2 - b_1b_2) + (a_1b_2 + b_1a_2)i$$

For the addition case, you add up all of the real parts (the $a$'s) and add up all of the imaginary parts (the $b$'s) separately.

For the multiplication case, it's very similar to the FOIL (first, outside, inside, last) method. The main surprise that comes out is $b_1b_2i^2 = -b_1b_2$, because $i^2 = -1$. (Multiplying two purely imaginary numbers gives you a real number!)

As for the identity $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$, you can write down the Taylor expansion of each term to see that they're equal.

Have fun!